# Android Studio APK not updating buildVersion

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm trying to update an Android app and upload it to the play store, but I keep getting an error that it's using an old versionCode.

I've updated the `versionCode` parameter in my build.gradle file, but when I run `build signed Bundle/APK` I notice that the data of the APK is never updated.

I'm not overly familiar with Android Studio - primarily coming from an iOS background, but as far as I can tell this should be all that's needed?

There are no build errors or warnings, and I'm using the "locate" prompt from within Android Studio itself to find the build so I'm not sure what's going on.

I'm using Android Studio version 3.2.1 and it's the latest build as confirmed by check for updates.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

I've tried restarting Android Studio and cleaning the build, but neither has worked, I've always hit the 'sync gradle file' as well after making a change

Comment: First Sync project. Then click on Clean Project option under Build. Then try to generate signed apk again

Comment: Just added an edit prior to your comment, I've already done both of those and it's not worked

Comment: At the time of generating apk did you checked both the version checkbox V1 and V2? And selected release option for build variant.

Comment: I was using the "Android App Bundle" option for generating for the store which doesn't include those checkboxes, going through the "APK" option from the generate APK menu though appears to have worked. Odd as surely building for the store should be the default. It seemed to update other files, just not the APK itself

Comment: Have you changed version name also?

Comment: No it’s all fixed as per my comment above

Comment: Try increasing thd `versionCode` once again! And then upload the `app.aab` file again. Because you have changed the versionCode and then again it caused error, you may need to do all the things like File>Invalidate Cache and then restart. And then build the app again with increase versionCode. The try uploading. Your error may be resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as alluded to in the comments, the fix that worked for me was :

I was using the "Android App Bundle" option for generating for the store which doesn't include the checkboxes for `V1` & `V2`, going through the "APK" option from the `generate APK menu` though appears to have worked. Odd as surely building for the store should be the default. It seemed to update other files, just not the APK itself

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S in Android Studio.
2. app -> Flavors -> defaultConfig -> versionCode (Increment the version number).
3. Click OK to trigger the Gradle build.
4. Generate the Android App Bundle and check.

[image: Product Structure Window]
[image: Gradle Build]